# Travelling to the UK as spouse of EU citizen, during 2020 transitional period

Tags: visas, uk, eu, family

I am an EU citizen. My wife is not. We live in an EU country different from my home country and she has a residence card for "family member of EU/EEA citizen".

Can we travel together to the UK right now without getting a visa?

When the UK was still an EU member, it was possible to travel there together without my spouse needing to get a visa. Does the same rule apply now during this transitional period?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So far [the same rules](https://www.gov.uk/transition) apply. What happens next year is anybody's guess.